# MySQL trigger and procedure not updating data correctly

Tags: mysql

I have a small database with a table named software_product that has an attribute named "build_status". The value of this can either be "usable", "ready", "not-ready". This value comes from the lowest status of all the software product components, which is held in another table (component status comes from an inspection).

What I am trying to get to work is a trigger on my table inspection that when an insert occurs, it sets the new component status and then updates the software product build status(s) if needed. Below is my MySQL statements. If anyone could help find the problem of why my build_status remains NULL, I would be greatly appreciative.

Thank you!

Table Creation:

```
create table Software_Product (
productID int,
name varchar(100),
version varchar(20),
build_status varchar(15),
primary key (productID)
);

create table People (
personID int,
name varchar(40),
seniority date,
primary key (personID)
);

create table Components (
componentID int,
name varchar(100),
ownerID int,
status varchar(15),
size int,
programming_language varChar(15),
primary key (componentID),
foreign key (ownerID) references People(personID)
);

create table Software_Build (
productID int,
componentID int,
foreign key (componentID) references Components(componentID),
foreign key (productID) references Software_Product(productID)
);

create table Inspection (
personID int,
componentID int,
score int,
description text,
date date,
foreign key (personID) references People(personID),
foreign key (componentID) references Components(componentID)
);
```

Trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$
create trigger updateStatus1
after insert
on inspection
    for each row begin
        declare foo varchar(15);
        if(new.score > 100 or new.score < 0)
        then
            signal sqlstate '45000';
        end if;
        if(new.score >= 90)
        then
            update components
            set status = 'ready'
            where new.componentID = components.componentID;
        end if;
        if(new.score < 90 or new.score >= 75)
        then
            update components
            set status = 'usable'
            where new.componentID = components.componentID;
        end if;
        if(new.score < 75)
        then
            update components
            set status = 'not-ready'
            where new.componentID = components.componentID;
        end if;
        call getLowestStatus(new.componentID,@output);
        select @output into foo;
        call updateStatusOnSP(new.componentID,foo);
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

getLowestStatusProcedure

```
DELIMITER $$
create procedure getLowestStatus(
    in icomponentID int, out ostatus varchar(15))
begin
    if((select distinct 1 from (select status
        from components
        where components.componentID = icomponentID) as newTable
        where status = 'ready') = 1)
    then
        set ostatus = 'ready';
    end if;
    if((select distinct 1 from (select status
        from components
        where components.componentID = icomponentID) as newTable
        where status = 'usable') = 1)
    then
        set ostatus = 'usable';
    end if;
    if((select distinct 1 from (select status
        from components
        where components.componentID = icomponentID) as newTable
        where status = 'not-ready') = 1)
    then
        set ostatus = 'not-ready';
    end if;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

updateStatusOnOP

```
DELIMITER $$
create procedure updateStatusOnSP(in icomponentID int,
    in istatus varchar(15))
begin
    update software_product
    inner join software_build on
    software_build.componentID = icomponentID
    set software_product.build_status = istatus;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Why the JOIN in `updateStatusOnSP`?

Comment: should I just do "set software_product.build_status = istatus where software_build.componentID = icomponentID"?

Comment: I don't see any particular reason needed for the join unless you wanted to make absolutely positively sure only `software_product` rows that have a match in `software_build` get updated. (...and yeah, that `where` looks right.)

Comment: Can you provide a small dataset that can be used to reproduce you problem?